# Easiest way to automatically copy files between computers

Tags: linux, shell, scp

I am trying to write a script which will essentially copy and file in a certain folder to a folder on another computer. My first thought was SCP, but I don't know if I can automate SCP by adding a password to the command(from what I have heard this is not possible, or very difficult).

So basically I am trying set up a folder on a mac or linux box which will accept files without prompting for a password (or it can get a password which I can send through a script).

I am sure there is an easy way to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scp/rsync etc with keyfiles so they don't prompt for a password (this is the better way of using them)

http://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and

Answer (score 1):

Your first thought was correct. If you [set up the ssh keys](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) on the various machines, you can scp (and ssh) with no password needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp with [ssh key authentication](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Networking/Public_key_authentication_with_ssh), or you could setup [rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) and limit access by IP.